# Nautilus crashes when trying to open another window by right-clicking the Nautilus icon on the dock and then selecting "Documents" (Ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: nautilus, crash, wayland, 21.04

When I right-click the Nautilus icon on my dock while at least one Nautilus window is already open, I can select "Documents" in the appearing menu. This should open another Nautilus window showing my `~/Documents` folder, but instead, it causes all existing Nautilus windows to close. The same happens when I select "Downloads", "Music", "Pictures", or "Videos", but "New Window" works normally.

[image: Screenshot of menu]

If I open Nautilus from the command line and then do the things described above, I can see that it crashes with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. 
How can I fix this? Is this a known bug? I already tried reinstalling Nautilus and deleting `~/.nautilus`, but it didn't help.

### Update/Solution

Apparently, Wayland was causing the problem. Now I'm using Xorg and the bug has disappeared.

Comment: Bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1934579

Comment: @koyakun Thank you for reporting this bug. But even if it gets fixed, I will still continue to use Xorg because Wayland causes a lot of other programs to crash/behave weirdly.

Comment: Understood. Would you mind confirming the bug though please?

Comment: @koyakun I have confirmed that this bug affects me. Do I have to confirm something else?

Comment: Thanks! That might be enough. Depends on the developers.

Comment: Can you `ls -hal ~` and paste the results?. In many cases thing like that are caused by inadvertently having set some permissions for root, excluding own user.

Comment: @Carles Mateo Sorry, I already reinstalled my system and I am now using 20.04.