# how to make firefox's picture in picture window always on top?

Tags: firefox, video, window-manager, mozilla, playback

Having the video on top of other windows is the point of Picture in Picture feature in Firefox and it is the default behavior in windows, but in Ubuntu, Firefox's picture in picture is not on top by default. every time i enable it, i should go to menu and make it "always on top" (look at picture).

is there any solution for this annoying behavior?

i use firefox 94 (snap package) in ubuntu 21.10 with gnome 40 on wayland.

[image]

Comment: I found this extension https://github.com/medenagan/window-corner-preview  from this link which describes it https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/floating-video-ubuntu-gnome-extension  I can't guarantee it will work with your configuration but it may be worth at least looking into.

Comment: This user was also using wayland on 21.04 and ended up 1. reporting a bug, 2. switching to xorg without any issues.  Here's the post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344175/nautilus-crashes-when-trying-to-open-another-window-by-right-clicking-the-nautil  Perhaps you may want to check bug reports and/or switch to xorg and see if you have the same issue with picture-in-picture.

Comment: Checked with apt version of Firefox, it also has the same issue. Seems like a Wayland thing indeed.

Comment: @TBr yes i checked it in xorg and it seems work correctly there. it is a wayland problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can quite easily be done with a Gnome Extension - you first need to install [GNOME Shell integration Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) and then this:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4691/pip-on-top/